# Can I render HTML code inside an XSLT template

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am using ASP.NET Core and C# 4. I am using AutoMapper to map an entity into another which is generated by xsd and is used for its data to be written in a PDF file. For the PDF styling I'm using XSLT.
The problem is, one of the properties of the entity is rich text, such that a user can enter bold, italic, bullet points etc. When this is saved into the database it is saved as an HTML string, something in the form of :

```
<p><strong><em>Text here</em></strong></p>
```

When exporting this, it is rendered as a full string and displayed exactly that way on the PDF file.
My question is, is there a possibility for the XSLT to render the HTML code and display it as rendered HTML instead of plain text HTML tags and text?

I have tried using `<xsl:output version="1.0" method="html" indent="yes"/>` and `<xsl:template match="html">` but neither of those work. I am not using the xsl:value-of tag in my code, so I cannot use the disable-output-escaping attribute.

I am using Altova to edit the XSLT and the output s XSLT-FO. Here is a small (incomplete) snippet of the xslt file:

```
<fo:table-body start-indent="0pt">                               
<xsl:variable name="altova:tablerows">
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="3" border-bottom-style="none" border-left-style="none" border-right-style="none" border-top-style="none" border="solid 1pt gray" padding="2pt" display-align="center">
    <fo:block text-align="justify">
      <fo:inline font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="10pt" font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:text>DESCRIPTION:</xsl:text>
      </fo:inline>
      <fo:block/>
      <xsl:for-each select="n1:Description">
        <xsl:variable name="value-of-template_13">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:variable>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the XSLT processor you use, what is the output format of the XSLT you have, is that XSL-FO or HTML/XHTML? What are you using instead of `xsl:value-of` exactly, why don't you show us minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated the question content.

Answer (score 0):

If the XSLT creates XSL-FO then your XSLT will need to transform any XHTML snippets to XSL-FO. If the XHTML is inside the XML input as normal elements it is simply a task of e.g. `<xsl:template match="strong"><fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:apply-templates/></fo:inline></xsl:template>` and further templates to transform the other elements. If the HTML is stored escaped or in a CDATA section you first need to parse it, easy in XSLT 3 with e.g. `parse-xml` or `parse-xml-fragment`. Altova since 2017 R3 supports XSLT 3 I think.

Comment: I have a global xsl:template in my code, everything else is embedded in it, so if I change the match from / to anything else, it throws an error saying "Data at the root level is invalid."